# How to use nanoScroller with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, nanoscroller

I have a problem with [nanoScroller](https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS). I am using Angularjs on the porject.I've a directive where I want to call the nanoScroller. It looks like this:

```
  <a ng-click='show-me'>Show Me</a>
  <div class='nano' ng-show='show-me' style='height:100px'>
   <ol class='nano-content'>
     <li ng-repeat='post in posts'>
       {{post.title}}
     </li>
   </ol>
  </div>
```

I need that `.nano` element has the scroller. When I press `show-me`, div opens which has a height of 100px. I also make a call of nanoScroller in this directive: `angular.element(".nano").nanoScroller()`
But scroll doesn't appear. 
Maybe this is related to the fact that nano elements are not present on the page yet and nanoScroller is already called for it?
I tried to use nanoScroller [directive](https://github.com/maxaon/angular-nanoscroller) but I get the following [bug](http://plnkr.co/edit/mR9FnBg0lfNSCtRPOfT6?p=preview) with it: when changing the height of the div with "This is item" content, scroll of the whole page moves up. This can be replicated by scrolling the page to the bottom and pressing Add item button several times.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to call `.nanoScroller()` when you know the element is visible. I recommend wrapping it in a timeout so it will update when the DOM is updated, by adding the following to your Angular Controller methods that handle changes to posts (i.e. `getPosts()`, `addPost()`, etc)..

```
// refresh nanoscroller
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".nano").nanoScroller();
}, 250);
```

In your case, you'll also need to add it to your `show-me` method, unless `show-me` is a simple boolean, in which case you'll need to pop the `setTimeout()` into a [`$scope.$watch()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) block that watches for changes to `show-me`, something like this (again, in your Controller)..

```
$scope.$watch('show-me', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue === true) {
    // refresh nanoscroller
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".nano").nanoScroller();
    }, 250);
  }
});
```

Comment: I would recommend using the Angular $timeout here instead of the vanilla JS version.

Comment: I disagree, $timeout causes an extra digest cycle, in my example scope variables are not being modified.

Comment: I should have clarified why I suggested $timeout. It provides a promise, which I find very useful. You are correct though, if you're looking to save digest cycles and you don't need a promise, use setTimeout. In my experience on a team it's easier or us all to just use $timeout, then we can all expect a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Wrapper for nanoScrollerJS with AngularJS lifecycle integration.

https://github.com/maxaon/angular-nanoscroller

[DEMO PLUNKER](http://embed.plnkr.co/pnSkmuRc7HjXjMG0DdrT/preview)